# Posting NSNotification from object inside SKScene error

Tags: sprite-kit, nsnotifications

I have SKScene controlled by ViewController. Inside this SKScene I have an playing board object (derived from NSObject) with some procedures. I need to post a notification from one of it's procedures (playing board procedures). Inside ViewController I have an observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rowBangEmitAtPosition:) name:@"rowBangN" object:nil];
```

and inside playing board's procedure I have :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"rowBangN" object:self userInfo:@{@"position":point}];
```

The object is part of SKScene (as variable). But this notification is never triggered. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Post your implementation of rowBangEmitAtPosition: and the order in which the methods are called. Meaning: be sure you have registered the observer *before* you post the notification.

Comment: I register the observer during -(void)viewDidLoad and I am initializing scene and it's objects during -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews, so I think it is ok.

Comment: Have you tried using NSLog or a breakpoint to verify that the method is not being called?

Comment: yes, breakpoint and NSLog, both, but it is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - when I put into posting code object:nil instead of object:self, it is working. i don't know why, but it works :).
Thanks to all.